# Disable `pip` retry installing packages - Speedup installation

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have a custom pip repository which is used inside my company but not outside. Now every time I'm at home and want to install something eg. `pip install pandas` it is trying also the "company" repo. Even decreasing the timeout pip still tries multiple times which takes a long time.

What can I do to speed up?

```
[global]
timeout = 1
extra-index-url = http://foo.bar/packages
trusted-host = pypi-dev.foo.bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip will ignore settings in the pip.conf if you run it with the '--isolated' option.

```
pip install --isolated <package>
```